# Is there an Internet resource for GPS timeline?

Tags: gps

I'm looking for a timeline of the evolution of GPS technology and accuracy for both civilian and military systems (since the advent of GPS).  Any info will help.

Comment: For older history (up to the mid-1990s), try the first chapter of the AIAA GPS "blue books". See http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/book/10.2514/4.866388 - online but not free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that there's a single comprehensive history, but possibly the best place to search is the folks who created it - the US Military.

Try a search for: `gps history site:mil`

Some results that may be of interest:

- [Timation and GPS Satellite History](http://ncst-www.nrl.navy.mil/NCSTOrigin/Timation.html) - Acronym heavy, detailed, describes the history of the science/engineering behind it.
- [Global Positioning System satellite achieves 20 years on-orbit](http://www.afspc.af.mil/news/story.asp?id=123232581)  - A more generic history
- [The Story of GPS](http://www.darpa.mil/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=2565) - Longer term generic history.
- https://gps.afspc.af.mil/gpsoc/GpsDocumentation.aspx - GPS documentation.
- [GPS: Theory, Practice and Applications](http://www.pdhonline.org/courses/l116/l116.htm)
- [Johnny Appleseed G P S - The Theory and Practice of GPS](http://]http://www.ja-gps.com.au/what-is-gps.aspx)
- And of course, don't forget wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System - lots of references!